# jQuery ajax, firefox with 302 redirects?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, firefox

I'm having problems in Firefox with 302 redirects coming from my Rails app.

Right now I have

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/model/33',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'authenticity_token=efjowiejfoiwej&_method=put&model[value]=aaa',
    complete: myFunc
});

function myFunc() {
    //do what I want
}
```

This works fine in other browsers, but in Firefox nothing happens, even using a `complete` callback instead of just a success.

Anything I can missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't completely solve it, but requesting the output as JSON worked, so
`url: '/model/33.json'`

Comment: Probably because your Server side code doesn't redirect .json requests where as it was for /model/33